# Text to speech playing automatically

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

I have a text to speech function in my android app that works to an onClick event, there is an issue  when the activity starts, the text to speech starts without clicking the button, is there a line of code I can put in to stop this happening, thank you.

```
package com.androidhive.texttospeech;

import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AndroidTextToSpeechActivity extends Activity implements
    TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private TextToSpeech tts;
    private Button button1;
    private TextView txtText;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    txtText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtText);

    // button on click event
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            speakOut();
        }

    });
 }

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // Don't forget to shutdown!
    if (tts != null) {
        tts.stop();
        tts.shutdown();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
 }

@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

        int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);

        // tts.setPitch(5); // set pitch level

        // tts.setSpeechRate(2); // set speech speed rate

        if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
            Log.e("TTS", "Language is not supported");
        } else {
            button1.setEnabled(true);
            speakOut();
        }

    } else {
        Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed");
    }

    }

 private void speakOut() {

    String text = txtText.getText().toString();

    tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why this happens is because you invoke speakOut# In the onInit() method, remove speakOut():

```
 if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
            Log.e("TTS", "Language is not supported");
        } else {
            button1.setEnabled(true);
          //  speakOut();
        }
```

Comment: I just realised that sorry

Comment: No problem. It happens :)

Comment: by any chance would you have a soliton to my other question on the tabs?  :)

Comment: Check your layout file, and check the min sdk version. Also you should highlight line 126

Answer (score 0):

I saw these codes in onInit(), which will be called after the TextToSpeech is instantiated and initialized successfully. See the speakOut() here? That's what causes your problem.

```
if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
            || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
        Log.e("TTS", "Language is not supported");
} else {
    button1.setEnabled(true);
    speakOut();
}
```